Limit bandwidth of a physical interface, turn a 10G link into a 1G link
I want a given network card to behave as if it were a slower network card. Like if the 1G interface in my laptop would actually be a 100M or 10M interface. One way of doing that is of course dig out my old 10mbit hub back from the days, and use that for this purpose.
I'm sure there is a "software solution" for that. And indeed, it appears as if the tc command and the tbf feature is able to do that.
Unfortunately, I do not fully grasp the concept to achieve what I wrote above. It seems there is some math involved to take the assumed link speed into account /sys/class/net/*/speed, likely the MTU from /sys/class/net/*/mtu, and the tick rate of the system. I'm not sure if the latter is still required these days with "current" distro kernels (I have CONFIG_NO_HZ=y and CONFIG_HZ_300=y for example).
How would a shell script look like to make such feature more generic? Like bash link-bandhwidth.sh <interface> 10m|100m|1G|2.5G|10G
Edit:
As suggested by @vidarlo, changing the link speed does actually work. I was able to change the list of advertised speeds for individual ports on the switch. I had mixed results with using ethtool, even on mlx5 cards which offered a number of different speeds.
I also have a mlx4 card which supports just a single speed. Here I tried the suggested, but incomplete, nc command. Hence the question how to programmatically generate the optimal values. This part remains unanswered, until now. For me a command like this worked on a fixed speed 10G link:
tc qdisc add dev $interface root tbf rate 2000mbit latency 1ms burst 2000mbit

This behaves like a hypothetical 2G card, but most likely the latency and burst values have room for improvement. I also tried 1000mbit and 100mbit with the expected results.

May I ask, why do you want a slower network card?

Use ethtool:
ethtool -s $IFACE speed 1000
Note that generally many SFPs only support a single speed. Running ethtool $IFACE will show supported rates and modes.
In addition, you can use tc to reduce available bandwidth; this does nothing to the link speed of the card, but it can shape the data stream:
tc qdisc add dev $IFACE root tbf rate 100mbit

thank you. But this changes nothing at all, data still flow at wirespeed. But only initially, it slows down later on. So effectively, this does not answer the question AFAICS.

ethtool can set line speed.

Using ethtool does apparently depend on the selected speed and the used card. For me it fails with mlx5 and 100G links. Only 1G mode transfers in 1G mode.

What problem are you attempting to solve?

moreover it is mostly easier to do it on the switch

As already noted, have a look at ethtool.
First run ethtool <ifname> and have a look at Supported link modes and Link partner advertised link modes. The intersection of the two sets gives you the link speeds available at both ends of the cable and to which you can limit the speed of the physical link.
After that have a look at ethtool man page, right under advertise option. Translate the speed(s) into appropriate bit masks and issue (as root) ethtool -s <ifname> advertise <number> to limit the speed(s) to indicated by bits in <value>.
